# converting NSJSON to NSDictionary and how to get values

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary

This is a NSJSON from response.

```
[{"code":"000","msg":"normal","data":
     [{"_master_id":"",
       "_locale":"kr",
       "c_url":"http://###.co.kr/##",          
       "c_server_ip":"###.co.kr",
       "c_server_port":"#####",
       .........
     }]
}]
```

and I converted this NSJSON to NSDictionary using this

```
NSDictionary *recivedDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                    error:&error];
```

then it become this

```
[{
    code = 000;
    data =     (
                {
            "_locale" = kr;
            "_master_id" = "";
            "c_url" =  ####
            .....             
     }
  );
   msg: ####;
}]
```

The double quotes are gone.
I want to get the data from the dictionary, but I can't get values from the dictionary using

```
let RESP_DATA : NSDictionary? = foo.object(forKey: "data") as?NSDictionary
RESP_DATA == nil, true
```

How can i get "data" from the dictionary??.. Thank you

Comment: in your response, `data` is array not dictionary

Comment: your JSON started with array `NSArray *recivedDictionary` not `NSDictionary *recivedDictionary`

Comment: But I don't know how to handle the values.. do I have to convert the data to NSArray ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
NSDictionary * recivedDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e][0]["data"][0];
if (recivedDictionary.count > 0 ) {
NSString * master_id = recivedDictionary["_master_id"];

}
```

Comment: @Anbu.karthik PLS CHECK EDIT ANSWER.

Comment: @Minsookim CHEK THE EDIT ANSWER.

Comment: @dahiya_boy I just have tried your sol, actually I got a response after once converting NSJSON to 'NSDictionary as [AnyHashable : Any] !' and I 'let receiveDic : NSDictionary = responseDictionary as NSDicionary' then it came this error message "Fatal error : unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: @dahiya_boy I have to get values on swift codes.. I forgot that

Comment: Sorry I don't know Objective-C and swift literally.. question is not good at all

Comment: @Minsookim In which language you want, your quest have obj-c tag.

Comment: @dahiya_boy Ok sorry for that, I Tried the Objective-C code, it terminated due to signal 6
`NSDictionary * recivedDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error][0]["@data"][0];`

Comment: @Minsookim pls give me url, I will check it and then re answer you accordingly. AND specify in which lang you r using obj-c or swift?

Comment: @dahiya_boy Thanksful! this code is work for me `recivedDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error]["@data"];`